# Check if array contain integer and generate integer array without duplicate elements

Tags: java, arrays

How would I make it so that the line that says `array.equals(guess)` works and how would I change the load values method into not allowing duplicate numbers?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Assignment {

    private static int[ ] loadValues(){
        int[] groupOfValues = new int[5];
        Random randomized = new Random();

        for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
          groupOfValues[index] = randomized.nextInt(39) + 1;
        }
        return groupOfValues;
    }
    private static void displayOutcome(int [ ] array, int guess){
          if(array.equals(guess)){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congrats, your guess of " + guess + " was one of these numbers:\n" 
                  + Arrays.toString(array));
          }
          else{
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, your guess of " + guess + " was not one of these numbers:\n" 
                  + Arrays.toString(array));
          }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

          int guessedConvert;
          String guess;

          do{
          guess = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Guess a number from 1-39");
          guessedConvert = Integer.parseInt(guess);     
          }while(guessedConvert < 1 || guessedConvert > 39);

          displayOutcome(loadValues(), guessedConvert);



    }
}
```

Comment: The array is an object containing 5 integers, the int is a primitive variable representing just 1 integer.  These two things can never be "equal" by the Java standard.  Try expanding on the logic you're trying to implement in the code, and tell us what problems you're running in to.

Comment: Arrays have no separate member function named "equals", so you defer to the Object "equals" function.  It requires an Object as it's operand.  So you *can't* make `array.equals(guess)` work, no matter how hard you try.

Answer (score 3):

Searching though an array requires a loop:

```
boolean found = false;
for (int i = 0 ; !found && i != array.length ; i++) {
    found = (array[i] == guess);
}
if (found) {
    ...
}
```

To figure out if there are duplicates in `loadValues` add a similar code snippet *inside* the outer loop:

```
for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
    boolean found = false;
    int next = randomized.nextInt(39) + 1;
    // Insert a loop that goes through the filled in portion
    ...
    if (found) {
        index--;
        continue;
    }
    groupOfValues[index] = next;
}
```